# Find $2+2\sin(\alpha)$ knowing that $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{5}{12}$

Tags: trigonometry

> The triangle [ABC] represented in the picture is isosceles, with the
>   line from B to C = the line from B to A = 1 and the angle at ABC =
>   2$\alpha$ with $\alpha \in ]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[$
>
> [image]
>
> $f$ is the function that gives the perimeter of the triangle for
>   $\alpha$, in radians:
>
> $$f(\alpha) = 2+2\sin(\alpha)$$
>
> Determine the exact value of the perimeter knowing that $\tan \alpha =
>  \frac{5}{12}$

I tried:

- $\tan \alpha = \frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}$
- $\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha} = \frac{5}{12}$
- $f(\alpha) = 2+2\cdot \frac{5}{12} \cdot \cos \alpha$
- $\cos \alpha = ???$

What do I do next? How do I solve this?
(Note that I can't use $\arctan$)

Comment: I see you are slowly expanding on topics outside of calculus... unless this is all meant to be calculus related.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't know myself. I'm just following the book and it never distiguishes between anything, it's either "derivatives", "limits", "trigonometry", etc... it never really refers to anything as calculus, or algebra or whatever. What I've been calling calculus is really either limits, derivatives, logarithms and other scientific-ish stuff.

Comment: Haha, okay then.  I hope the lack of limit questions means you've mastered them ;)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think I might have, actually :)

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

[image]

That is, use Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Hint #2 - this is *similar* to your triangle, OP.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides: $P = f(\alpha)\implies P^2 = 4+8\sin\alpha+4\sin^2\alpha= 4+\dfrac{8(P-2)}{2}+\dfrac{4}{\csc^2\alpha}=4P-4+\dfrac{4}{1+\cot^2\alpha}=4P-4+\dfrac{4\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}\implies (P-2)^2 = \dfrac{4\tan^2\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}\implies P = 2+\dfrac{2\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\alpha}}$. To get the answer, substitute $\tan\alpha = \dfrac{2}{5}$ into the equation above.